# A strange recipe

Tags: cryptic-clues

I was looking through my grandma's cookbook when I saw this recipe:

> Heat consists of 1692 symbols, delicious hesitance, headless escape, glasses, and a green hat.

No further instructions were provided. What does that mean?

**Answer enumeration: `6'1 4`**

Comment: is your answer in your post? Cuz you aren't supposed to do that

Comment: No, the 6’1 4 looks like the enumeration for the cryptic clue I think @Ankit

Comment: @El-Guest You are correct, that is the enumeration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, with thanks to @MacGyver88 and @El-Guest for the final nudge regarding the 'green hat', here is the final answer...

*Heat consists of 1692 symbols, delicious hesitance, headless escape, glasses, and a green hat. (6'1,4)*

> (NB Although in a traditional cryptic clue part of this would be a definition, the OP says in comments below that this isn't entirely the case here. Instead I think the mention of '*Heat*' here is more just thematic and loosely in keeping with the final answer...)
>
>  *1692 symbols:* Elements 16 and 92 in the Periodic Table are Sulfur (**S**) and Uranium (**U**).
>
>  *delicious:* If something is delicious it makes you say '**MM**'.
>
>  *hesitance:* **ER**.
>
>  *headless escape:* The 'Escape' key on a keyboard is labelled 'Esc' - remove its head (i.e. the 'E') and you are left with '**SC**'.
>
>  *glasses:* This is an allusion to '**OO**' looking like a pair of glasses.
>
>  *a green hat:* With thanks to @MacGyver88 and @El-Guest, this is a reference to *Luigi* from the Mario computer game franchise. His green hat is emblazoned with an '**L**'. (This reading is less in keeping with a traditional cryptic clue, but go with it - everything pans out...)

Altogether then, we have an answer:

> **SUMMER'S COOL!** This phrase would fit with the fact this puzzle was posted at the start of June (the first month of summer in the Northern Hemisphere).

Comment: Nice thinking @Stiv

Comment: rot13(Yhvtv unf n terra ung jvgu na "Y" ba vg.)

Comment: You are VERY CLOSE. Have a look at Mario.

Comment: Also the “Heat is” is not part of the answer.

Comment: Stiv: the green hat from Mario would have an rot13(Y sbe YHVTV), giving you the final letter instead of K.

Comment: @MacGyver88 Nice spot! :)

Comment: @El-Guest Aha, I see that now. It's a shame there is no definition in the cryptic clue then, but I'll adjust the answer all the same...

Comment: @Stiv agreed — I spent too long trying to include heat somewhere (Q? Definition?) but nice job on the solve

Comment: Nicely done! I can't award the bounty for another 6 hours, so here's a green checkmark :)

Comment: And here's the bounty.

Comment: Aha, well thank you very much @matt :)

Comment: No problem :) can't wait for your next puzzle @Stiv

Answer (score 4):

Give @Stiv the check mark for this.

Heat consists of 1692 symbols,

> 16 is the atomic number for sulfur (S), and 92 is the atomic number for uranium (U)

delicious

> When something is delicious, you’d say MM

hesitance

> When one hesitates, they say ER

headless escape

> The escape key is ESC, without head gives SC

glasses

> Looks like OO

and a green hat.

> Luigi wears the green hat in the Mario series, with a big L on it.

Altogether yields

> SUMMER’S COOL, of which @Stiv got uniquely 70% and is more than deserving of the tick.

Comment: You’re right on with the glasses.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

I think it may be referring to

> Witchcake

Reason:

> $1692$ is known for Salem Witch Trials. Witchcake had an ingredient, the ergot fungus which is known to give hallucinations (delicious hesitence).

Quoting [history channel](https://www.history.com/news/salem-witch-trials-first-accused-woman-slave?li_source=LI&li_medium=m2m-rcw-history) and [[2]](https://www.history.com/news/7-bizarre-witch-trial-tests?li_source=LI&li_medium=m2m-rcw-history)

> Tituba cared for the Parris children, and Parris’ daughter and niece were among the first girls who began showing strange symptoms in 1692. The girls had been playing a fortune-telling game that involved dropping an egg white into a glass of water. Supposedly, the form the egg white took in the water could help predict whom the girls would marry and show the shapes of their future lives. After the girls saw a coffin in one of the glasses, they began barking like dogs, babbling and crying hysterically.

Thus,

> This is how glasses come into the picture. Also, I guess the green hat mentions the witches as they are usually shown wearing a green hat. If it was `5'1 4` then the answer would be either witch's mark, devil's mark, or as to recipe witch's cake. Or if it must be `6'1 4` then it may be Tituba's cake. And headless logic could mean: 1. The ergot fungus grows on the head of wheat and the spores escapes the head for reproduction 2. headless = losing one's mind. So, one eats the fungus and escapes into light headed delusion and hysteria. 3. Tituba (head of witchcraft) vanished from history without any trace and others escaped from being killed from the 7 tests.

Comment: Nice logic, but ... no.

Comment: Does the 'recipe' in the title actually mention a (normal) recipe?

Comment: If by “normal” you mean “something I could actually make”, no.